# Bluetooth gets disconnected on opening GUI from Computer.

Tags: android, bluetooth, pandaboard

I am pairing the Bluetooth of the pandaboard(which is running on Android ICS) with the PC. Now connection is established and I am able to send/receive the data through hyper terminal without any problem.

On my PC side, I have a GUI. Through this GUI only i want to send/receive the data through BT.

But when I try to open the GUI which is on my PC, the BT connection gets disconnected!!!

Why is this happenning?

Any idea on how to solve it?